# How to limit the range of scrollable x-axis in ApexCharts?

Tags: apexcharts, react-apexcharts

I'm using columns type chart. Just same chart with this example in apexchart demo.
[React Chart Demos > Column Charts > Stacked Columns](https://apexcharts.com/react-chart-demos/column-charts/stacked/)

**To-be**

When x-axis scroll reaches the left-most bar of the chart, make it no longer scrolls to the left. (same in right side of the chart)

**As-is**

x-axis scroll is infinite scroll.

Comment: How do you get this infinite scroll? I can't replicate that in the example you linked to. First of all I don't get any scroll unless I zoom in; then I can scroll by selecting the hand tool and dragging the canvas to the left or to the right. And it's actually too limited -- when I get to the left limit of the scroll I don't see the left rounded corner of the first bar (and the same to the right)

Comment: When use "Selection Zoom", you can check the infinite scroll.

1. Select 'selection zoom
2. Select the left or right range where bar doesn't exist.

In my case, since there is no 'home' button as shown in the example above, so it's quire difficult to return to the chart, where the data exists when if it's possible to scroll infinitely. So I want to make sure that the bar doesn't exist (or there's no data).

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't. After "Selection Zoom" I have to get to the hand tool, "panning", (otherwise it will continue to select for zoom) and the dragging is limited at both ends. Tested on macos with chrome, firefox, safari and edge

Comment: Oh, I see, you're using selection zoom to force your way beyond the margin. I think it's a bug. They are trying to limit the scroll, but they haven't thought to cover that manoeuvre yet

Comment: Oh, then I should report issue for ApexCharts as well. Thanks for watching though.